# Best Practice to Build a Java SDK for a REST API

Tags: java, rest, sdk

I'm about to develop a Java SDK against a REST API and would like to know what would be the best practice approach to building it. I've looked at Google and also used a number of SDKs which connect to REST APIs and there is never much consistency. I've come across some patterns which I find interesting and would like to know which one could be considered best practice, if any, or if there are alternatives?

I've provided sample / pseudo code to facilitate.

1) The models / requests / client are all separated. Example call:

```
Client client = new Client( ... credentials ... );

try {
    Something obj = client.post( new PostSomethingRequest( ..params... ) );
} catch( Exception oops ) { ...handle... }

try {
    Something obj2 = client.get( new GetSomethingRequest( id ) );
} catch( Exception oops ) { ...handle... }
```

2) The models and request are tied together and the client is separate. Example call:

```
Client client = new Client( ... credentials ... );

try {
    Something obj = client.post( new Something( ..params... ) );
} catch( Exception oops ) { ...handle... }

try {
    Something obj2 = client.get( new Something( id ) );
} catch( Exception oops ) { ...handle... }
```

3) The model contains everything. Example call:

```
Client.setCredentials( ... credentials ... );

Something obj = new Something( ..params... );
try {
    obj.post();
} catch( Exception oops ) { ...handle... }

try {
    Something obj2 = Something.get( id );
} catch( Exception oops ) { ...handle... }
```

If there are better ways of building this I'd also be glad to hear about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you build an SDK for a special REST API, I would use method names that represent the REST service calls and won't be so generic.

Comment: I agree. For a complex REST API the design would be different, for example, the AWS SDK is not as simple as this one and is structured in a very different way. However, we're very much straight forward and offer CRUD operations on a series of resources only.

Comment: Than you are not building a Java API for a REST service but a generic REST client library.